# Rails 3 - How to use stylesheet's compiled name inside javascript file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have javascript file in rails app, where i pull in the stylesheet like this -

```
   loadAssets: function(){ 
    var stylesheet = document.createElement('link');
    stylesheet.href = "<%= asset_path('lib/myStyles.css') %>"; 
    stylesheet.rel = 'stylesheet';
    stylesheet.type = 'text/css';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(stylesheet);
}
```

But asset_path helper used here, just gives plain myStyles.css name, where it should have been compiled name of that css file.

Because of this, i can't expire cache and get new myStyles.css file.

So, my question is, how can i get compiled name of this myStles.css file in my javascript file. Above code containing javascript file also gets compiled.

Comment: I would suspect that getting the asset pipeline to compile css before js can let the asset_path function yield the proper path?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= asset_path('lib/myStyles.css'), :digest => true) %>
```

Comment: you need to make sure it is a js.erb file to embed ruby

Comment: For sure. I assumed that if asset_path was returning any name at all for them that it was already a js.erb file.